# The "Interactable" layer from Unity is not visible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]
[image]

Here is the error itself

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerIneract : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Camera cam;
    [SerializeField]
    private float distanse = 3f;
    [SerializeField]
    private LayerMask mask;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<PlayerLook>().cam;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward);
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * distanse);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, distanse, mask))
        {
            if(hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>() != null)
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know how to fix this error? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you have mistaken a layer for a component, what is this Interactable component?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPPGnpV1Y1c&list=PLGUw8UNswJEOv8c5ZcoHarbON6mIEUFBC&index=2

Comment: not watching an entire tutorial.  have you debugged it at all is there even an interactable component on the object being hit?

Comment: I watched this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPPGnpV1Y1c&list=PLGUw8UNswJEOv8c5ZcoHarbON6mIEUFBC&index=2
7:10

Comment: Still not going to watch an entire tutorial.. you should be able to answer the questions ive asked

Comment: @Baton [in the very first minutes of your link](https://youtu.be/gPPGnpV1Y1c?list=PLGUw8UNswJEOv8c5ZcoHarbON6mIEUFBC&t=60) they create `public abstract class Interactable : MonoBehaviour { ... }` ... where is yours ...? What exactly does the error say? This has nothing to do with layers but with a c# class type ... Also `PlayerIneract` typo btw

Comment: in general btw shouldn't use `GetComponent` twice .. rather use [`TryGetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html) as in`if(hitInfo.collider.TryGetComponnet<Interactable>(out var interactable)){ /* use interactable */ }` ... (same way you can simply use `out var hitInfo` to make it a bit cleaner)